# What does the distribution of the savings rate in America look like?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

I know the average saving rate in the US is ~5%, but I'm curious about the distribution. An ideal answer would be a histogram with the data broken down by what proportion of population are saving at what percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How much do people save?

[image]
[Report on the Economic Well-Being of U.S. Households in 2014, Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System, p. 22](http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/2014-report-economic-well-being-us-households-201505.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

About 90% of the population has very little or negative savings. The savings is driven by the upper middle class which typically saves 10% or so of pretax income. You can look at the net worth percentiles here to get a rough idea:

http://www.shnugi.com/networth-percentile-calculator/